# How to validate number is greater than 0 in python?

Tags: python, flask

I tried to validate the returned number from input form in python. The input value must be a number and greater than 0.

My script is like this:

**hello.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def checNumber():
    if request.method=='POST':

        number = request.form['Number']


        try:
            if int(number) < 0:
                raise 'Number should be greater than 0'
        except:
                raise 'Please enter number only'

    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

**hello.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='' method='POST'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="KhmerName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Number" name="Number" placeholder="Please enter number only">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

After I click on submit form, if the inputted value is not a number (alphabet or something else) it will raise `'Please enter number only'`. However, if number is negative, it never raise `'Number should be greater than 0'`, yet the python regards it as not a number and raise `'Please enter number only'`.

I think a negative value is also a number.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the value of number before the `try` block is, in fact, the number that you entered?  `print` may be useful to check.

Comment: By the way, `< 0` doesn't check `== 0`, which is not "greater than 0"

Comment: @roelofs, If i just print not raise, it will validate correctly.

Comment: No, do `print(repr(request.form['Number']))`, before the try.

Comment: Add `print request.form['Number']`, and post the output of `input (number, negative number, or, alphabet)` will help a lot.

Comment: @MadLee, sure. with `print request.form['Number']`. If the input is a number (ex. 223), the output is 223. If the input is a negative number (ex. -223), the output is 223. and if it is the alphabet (ex. 'alpha'), the output is alpha. Thanks

Comment: @HouyNarun I run your code and the output of `-223` is `-223`!

Comment: @MadLee, Thanks for taking time test my script. I found that the `if-condition: if int(number) < 0:` was matched. However, statement `raise 'Number should be greater than 0'` caused an error (I don't know why), that cause the script jumped to `except` block. Why I knew this? Because I tested print statement, say `print 'hello'` in `if-clause` just right above statement `raise 'Number should be greater than 0'`. And if the input value is, let's say `-223` the word `hello` is printed, however the raise statement is in `except` block instead. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, `raise` key word will throw an exception and `except` will catch any exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raise 'Number should be greater than 0'
```

You expect this line will raise an exception and the `checNumber` function dump, but the exception caught by the `try ... except ...` block.

Try this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def checNumber():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        number_str = request.form['Number']
        try:
            number = float(number_str)
        except ValueError:
            number = None

        if number is None:
            raise ValueError('Please enter number only')
        elif number <= 0:
            raise ValueError('Number should be greater than 0')
        else:
            pass

    return render_template('hello.html')
```

Comment: That answer to my issue! Thanks very much Mad Lee :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    try:
        if int(number) < 0:
            raise 'Number should be greater than 0'
    except:
            raise 'Please enter number only'
```

Go with:

```
   try:
       if float(request.form['Number']) <= 0:
          raise 'Number should be greater than 0'
   finally:
       raise 'Please enter number only'
```

And if that does not help, let the exception from "int(number) < 0" raise through and see what caused the exception.

Comment: @cricket_007 absolutely, that would be the best... I'll edit the answer.

Comment: whatever input (number, negative number, or, alphabet), it only raised "please enter number only". Thanks.

Comment: @HouyNarun and if you remove the masking try structure all together, what exception do you get?

Comment: sure just this statement `if int(number) < 0: raise 'Number should be greater than 0'`, if the input is a number, it is fine, and if the input is `Negative Number`, it will raise `Number should be greater than 0`. If the input is alphabet (none numeric), it raise exception `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`. Thanks